# Java Generics with compilation error for extends base object

Tags: java, generic-programming, generic-collections

I have following class which contains map containing generics of list of objects. I need to put a method addElement() and kind of confused about type of object.

What should be type of argument on method addElement() ???

```
public class Tester{
   private final ConcurrentMap<Date, List<? extends BaseObject>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

 ...
 ...
 public void addElement(Date d, BaseObject o){
        ...
        ...
    List<? extends BaseObject> list = map.get(d);
    if (null == list) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    //add element
    list.add(o);<-------------- Compile error
    map.put(d,list); 
 }


}
```

***Solution*** 
Changing code to following will fix the issue, [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

public class Tester{
       private final ConcurrentMap> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

```
 ...
 ...
 public void addElement(Date d, BaseObject o){
        ...
        ...
    List<? super BaseObject> list = map.get(d);
    if (null == list) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    //add element
    list.add(o);<-------------- Compile error fixed
    map.put(d,list); 
 }


}
```

Comment: Is it `list` you should be adding or `o`?

Comment: You can't add anything to a `List<? extends Anything>` as it acts as `Producer`. You can use `? super ClassName` or `ClassName` so that you can add items to a List

Comment: I had typo error on earlier code snipet